# DataExporter tag - PrimeFaces - page only = "false"

Tags: jsf, primefaces, export, export-to-excel

I'm trying to export data from DataTable using DataExporter tag, but, DataExporter is exporting only first page data (page of the print), but I want to export data from all pages.

See below my button code and the screen.

Code:

```
                        <p:dataTable id="listaConsulta"  rowStyleClass="#{empty rowIx or rowIx mod 2 ne 0 ? 'jsfcrud_odd_row' : 'jsfcrud_even_row'}" rowIndexVar="rowIx"   value="#{funcionarioController.items}" var="item">
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Código"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.codigo}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column width="25%">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Nome"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.nome}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column width="10%">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Cpf"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.cpf}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Nascimento"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.datanascimento}">
                                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                                </h:outputText>
                            </p:column>
                           <p:column width="25%">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Cargo"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.cargo.descricao}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Telefone"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.fone}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Celular"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.celular}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Ativo"/>


                </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.estaAtivo}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:commandLink title="Editar" action="Create?faces-redirect=true&amp;includeViewParams=true">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{funcionarioController.selected}"/>
                                <h:graphicImage height="32" value="/image/file_edit.png" />
                            </h:commandLink>
                            <h:commandLink title="Ficha Registro" target="_blank"  action="#{funcionarioController.gerarRelatorioJasper}">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{funcionarioController.selected}"/>
                                <p:graphicImage value="/image/pdf.png" />
                            </h:commandLink>

                        </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:panelGroup>
                <br />
                <p:commandButton ajax="false"  immediate="true"  action="#{funcionarioController.prepareCreate()}"  value="#{bundle.ListFuncionarioCreateLink}"/>

                <p:spacer width="10px"/>
                <p:commandButton value ="Gerar Excel" ajax="false">
                    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="listaConsulta" fileName="dadosFuncionarios" encoding="utf-8" pageOnly="false"/>
                </p:commandButton>
```

Screen:

[image]

How do I solve this?

EDIT: I change the code inserting datatable and dataexporter entire code.

Comment: There is nothing  visible to export in your code. Might as well be that in your code you just have the page data... [mcve] please!!!

Comment: Kukeltje, sorry. I change the code inserting datatable and dataexporter entire code. Can you help me now?